# How can I backup all my jailbroken iPhone apps saves before restoring to new firmware?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, backup, restore

I have a jailbroken iPhone (3Gs, iOS 4.0.1, bb 5.13.04). I want to get jailbroken & unlocked 4.3.1 , but I cannot do it in other way than restoring from custom pwned firmware, so all my saves and app data will be erased.

How can I back up all my app data and games saves to restore them after firmware upgrade?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an insanely detailed step by step process on how to do this using the cydia app appbackup on http://applemonday.com/2011/04/jailbreak-data-apps-ios-appbackup/ which basically grabs all your app data and puts it in one folder for you to ssh into and get.

Comment: Is there any other way? I've installed AppBackup but it crashes right after splash screen :(

Comment: to be honest appbackup is just a method of going through the filesystem and grabbing specific files and then putting them back in their places, so let me do some more research, there are definitely other options

Comment: I love the google search term "better than x" http://www.pragmatixconsulting.com/iphoneApps/User_Guide.html and a guide to go with it since it is paid http://www.theiphoneguru.net/2010/11/22/guru-guide-back-up-and-restore-jailbreak-apps-for-ios-4-2/

Comment: Keep me updated!

Comment: @hobs, Paul Lefebvre mentioned PKGBackup, it also was mentioned in your links, but it is a bit unsuitable for me. As I see, there is no free tool except AppBackup which doesn't work at my phone. Nevertheless, thanks for your advices!

Comment: We could also do some research on what folders it backs up, or even use ssh and rsync to backup 100% of everything, but putting it back would be expected to be non-trivial.

Comment: Yes, I have some experience regarding that, I were just searchin some tool to automatize this process... It seems that I have to do everything manually as I've done somewhen :)

Answer (score 1):

PKGBackup ($7 from Cydia) will back up all your settings to Dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new app out there, called Datadeposit and it saves your data to your dropbox account whyle syncing it. Awesome! http://www.iphonehacks.com/2011/05/datadeposit-nifty-jailbreak-app-allows-you-to-save-iphone-app-data-in-the-cloud-dropbox.html